# What to use instead of IAuthenticator (read/write file via winforms to Google Drive)

Tags: winforms, authentication, google-drive-api

I am trying to write/read files to Google Drive from a Winforms app.  I've taken some of the sample code from projects Google has provided, but they all use IAuthenticator, which is no longer valid, from what I read.

I can do almost everything I need, except actually read the file (that I wrote) back from Google Drive, because I cannot figure out how to authenticate.  Saying another way, I can read the file metadata back, but need to authenticate before I use the DownloadUrl to read the file contents.  I cannot figure out how to get past Authentication.  Can anyone help?

Thank you